# How does org know my name?

Tags: org-export

Just org-exported something and my name was at the top of the exported
document.  How does org know my name?  On Fedora.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs looks up the currently logged in user in the
password database, and stores it in `user-full-name`, which org-mode then inserts when exporting. You can
edit its value using <kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd>.

See [(elisp) User Identification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/User-Identification.html) as suggested by @Basil